# PHP echo with variables and functions

Tags: php, variables, url, echo, page-refresh

I'm trying to create an automatic refresh url as below but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
<?php 
$lastid = 12345
redirect = echo the_permalink(get_option( 'cts_return_page' )).'?transid='.$lastid';
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='$redirect'">';
?>
```

The url I want it to redirect/refresh to would be http://example.com/page-from-options?transid=12345

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What problem you fetch??

Comment: You are using WordPress, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made a several mistakes in your code like

- You should not use `echo` like `$redirect = echo`.
- You have to use `$redirect` rather than `redirect`.
- No need to use `'` after `$lastid`.
- And use `;` after `12345`.
- **edit** Concatenate with `..` like `url='.$redirect.'`

Hope this will helps you.

```
<?php
  $lastid = 12345;
  $redirect = the_permalink(get_option( 'cts_return_page' )).'?transid='.$lastid;
 echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url='.$redirect.'">';
?>
```

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar Syntax error solved.. lol :D i doesnot run the code i just edited this directly that's why i made mistake.. now i just check the code in localhost and it is working fine now.. Thanx for suggestion :)

Comment: its not work in `localhost` ... or in online fiddle.. get error in `the_permalink` and `get_option` function !!

Comment: @RïshïKêshKümar have you checked it in wordpress?

Comment: no.. actually  its not setup in my local machine .. so !! i just try on the local server and get the the error . now  waiting for response from  `Jeremy`

Answer (score 1):

> **Solution:**

```
  <?php
    $lastid = 12345;

    $redirect = the_permalink(get_option( 'cts_return_page' )).'?transid='.$lastid;

    echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'; url ='<?php $redirect ?>' > ";
  ?>
```

---

### OR

```
<?php

     //$redirect = get_permalink(get_option( 'cts_return_page' )).'?transid='.$lastid;
     //$url = "http://example.com/page-from-options?transid=12345";

       $lastid = 12345;

    // Retrieve the `cts_return_page`, and storing it in a variable.
       echo $get_options = get_option('cts_return_page');

    //Displays the URL to the post:
      echo $redirect = the_permalink($get_options).'?transid='.$lastid;


   //echo " <meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1'; url ='http://example.com/<?php $redirect ?>' > ";

?>

<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1' url='http://example.com/<?php echo $redirect; ?>' >
```

> **Problems:**

- First `Syntax Error:` Semicolon ( `;` ) Missing after `$lastid = 12345` as Well as You used String Value Here Why ? `$lastid` its interger value so used like that ex:   `$lastid = 12345;`
- When You Assign the Value ( `=` ) then don't use `echo` , `echo` is actually used to print the value so avoid to used.
  -

Answer (score 0):

> You can not set with any variable value with echo statement  first you need set variable $redirect value after you can echo $redirect

```
<?php 
   $lastid = '12345'; // use semicolon
   $redirect = the_permalink(get_option('cts_return_page'))."?transid=".$lastid; // you made mistake here `echo` should not goes here
   echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url="'.$redirect.'">';
?>
```

Comment: You did't mention where the OP will change or what is the problem.

Answer (score -1):

You're using WordPress, right? I can guess by the `the_permalink` and `get_option` functions. If so, the following code should work for you.

More explanation: [edit]
See Nirav Joshi's for PHP mistakes you've made. Additionally, as you're using WordPress

- `the_permalink` actually echoes the url. You should use `get_permalink` to store the url in `$redirect` variable.

---

Use this code:

```
    $lastid = 12345;
    $redirect = get_permalink(get_option( 'cts_return_page' )) . '?transid=' . $lastid;
    echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1; url=' . $redirect . '">';
```

Comment: You did't mention where the OP will change or what is the problem.

Comment: Thanks. I was editing the answer while you were commenting.

Comment: Thanks @SougataBose. Corrected the variable name and function name as well.